# Should I use the memory_map option in pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, memory

I want to use a large Pandas DataFrame in a computationally-heavy algorithm.

I am not sure if I should use the `memory_map` option of the pandas `read_csv`. Does it make accessing the DataFrame during the algorithm iterations faster? Or does it only affect how the data is read into a DataFrame object?

Here is the option's description:

> `memory_map` : bool, default False
> If a filepath is provided for *filepath_or_buffer*, map the file object directly onto memory and access the data directly from there. Using this option can improve performance because there is no longer any I/O overhead.

Thank you.

Comment: After some tests, it does not seem to do much for some quick computations.

Comment: Can you be more specific on quick computations that you've tried? Feel free to add any test code you've run into your question. That being said, since `memory_map` is a parameter for `read_csv`, I am pretty sure it only affects how data is read, not how it is stored or accessed

Comment: it only affects how the data is read.

Comment: @DerekO By quick computations, I mean acessing two columns and multiplying them, doing the same with two rows (with `.iloc()`) and doing it for specific values with `.at()`.

Comment: @Marat the description talks about "acessing the data directly from memory", so it was not clear to me if it was the final DataFrame or the CSV file. But I guess the DataFrame is always in memory, so your answer makes sense. Thank you. Would you like to put that info as an answer below?

Comment: @JoãoBravo nah, making a proper answer explaining syscalls underlying file operations is a bit too much effort - perhaps, that's also the reason it wasn't explained in the docs. Please consider filing a bug in pandas asking to explain the difference.